# Ansible become and privileges best practices

Tags: security, configuration, ansible

I use Ansible to manage containers. I'm looking to be sure I follow best practices with users when I deploy. On that note:

1. Most of my playbooks have the become statements below. This (I think) is required for most activities, such as installing packages, moving system-wide configuration files, and adding/updating users. What do you do?

```
    become: yes
    become:method: sudo
```

2. Should I have a new user on the host to deploy to? Related to #1, I could modify this user's sudoers access to allow apt and other packages, but that is quite a bit of work and may change as modules change. It would allow me to isolate the user from SSH access if that were ever needed.
3. I'm not aware of other practices I should be following related to properly (in terms of security) applying a configuration management system. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 2):

We currently forbid using `become` when its not absolutely necessary and instead run our playbooks as the user accessing the server (for example `user1`) with a `-b` flag to enforce sudo application.

This helps because:

1. The user applying a playbook needs to provide the `-b` flag (i.e.: one extra layer of "security" - you can compare this with the statement "you should be root on a linux box when you dont need to").
2. You can run the playbook w/o `-b` for a check mode. It will tell you if anything needs to be done on that server without doing anything.